# Use of CASE in WHERE clause to Calc Units

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Sever 2014. The following query executes without a problem.

```
USE [DRILLHOLES_Export] 
GO

SELECT TOP 100 
    [DHGeochemistryAttr].[Id]
    ,[DHGeochemistry].[SampleId]
    ,[DHGeochemistry].[FromDepth]
    ,[DHGeochemistry].[ToDepth]
    ,[DHGeochemistry].[Units]
    ,[DHGeochemistryAttr].[DHGeochemistryId]
    ,[DHGeochemistryAttr].[AttributeValue]
    ,[DHGeochemistryAttr].[MRTDetailId]
    ,[dbo].[MRTDetail].[Units]
FROM 
    [dbo].[DHGeochemistryattr]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[MRTDetail] ON [dbo].[MRTDetail].[Id] = [DHGeochemistryAttr].[MRTDetailId]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[DHGeochemistry] ON [dbo].[DHGeochemistryAttr].DHGeochemistryId] = [dbo].DHGeochemistry].[Id]
WHERE 
    [AttributeColumn] = 'Au' 
    AND ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1 
    AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT) > 1 
    AND [MRTDetail].[Units] = 'ppm'
```

The values in the `[AttributeValue]` column can be in parts per million (ppm)
or parts per billion (ppb). The `[MRTDetail].[Units]` defines the units.

I want the query to report all values above 1 ppm or 1000 ppb; to this end I have tried the following `CASE` statement to the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 
    [AttributeColumn] = 'Au' 
    AND ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1 
    AND 
       CASE [MRTDetail].[Units]
          WHEN 'PPM' 
             THEN CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1  
          WHEN 'PPB' 
             THEN CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT) * 1000  > 1000
       END
```

I get the following error on the first `WHEN` line

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 70
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Could someone help?
Regards,
Peter

Comment: have you got a couple of rows of simple sample data?

Comment: CASE expression returning boolean values in WHERE? Why not use AND/OR instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a case statement. Then you could do something like this:

```
(
        CASE [MRTDetail].[Units]
        WHEN 'PPM' THEN
            (
                CASE WHEN CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            )
        WHEN 'PPB' THEN
            (
                CASE WHEN CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)*1000  > 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            )
        END
)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AND`/ `OR` instead:

```
WHERE [AttributeColumn] = 'Au' AND ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1 
AND
  (( [MRTDetail].[Units] = 'PPM' AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1 )
    OR 
   ( [MRTDetail].[Units] = 'PPB' AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)*1000  > 1000 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND`/`OR` instead:

```
WHERE [AttributeColumn] = 'Au' AND ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1 AND 
 (([MRTDetail].[Units] = 'PPM' AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1)
  OR
  ([MRTDetail].[Units] = 'PPB' AND CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)*1000  > 1000))
```

or perhaps:

```
WHERE [AttributeColumn] = 'Au' AND ISNUMERIC([AttributeValue]) = 1 AND 
 [MRTDetail].[Units] IN ('PPM','PPB) AND
 CAST([AttributeValue] AS FLOAT)  > 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note, I've simplified my solution by removing some of the casting and validation you have in your question to focus on the `CASE` statement.

You can do the following:

```
WHERE   CASE Units
              WHEN 'PPM' THEN Value * 1000
              WHEN 'PPB' THEN Value
            END > 1000
```

Runnable sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #t
    (
      Units VARCHAR(10) ,
      Value FLOAT
    )
INSERT  INTO #t
VALUES  ( 'PPM', 1.01 ),  -- > 1000 ppb
        ( 'PPB', 25000 ), -- > 1000 ppb
        ( 'PPB', 950 ),   -- < 1000 ppb
        ( 'PPM', 0.79 )   -- < 1000 ppb

SELECT  *
FROM    #t
WHERE   CASE Units
          WHEN 'PPM' THEN Value * 1000
          WHEN 'PPB' THEN Value
        END > 1000

DROP TABLE #t
```

Produces 2 rows with less than 1000 PPB:

```
Units   Value
PPM     1.01
PPB     25000
```